Quali sono i parametri per sanzionare?
In base a recenti e frequenti diatribe mi chiedo quali siano i parametri per sanzionare e che cosa si intenda per insulto. Visto che sono coinvolto molto direttamente, questa domanda la ritengo fondamentale. Quando uno viene definito "troll", l'affermazione passa senza problemi. In chat private mi viene poi risposto da parte dei mod. a mo' di "sì, non mi era sembrato adeguato, ma non sono intervenuto sperando che si appianasse". No, così non funziona. Non siamo nell'Italietta dove il vigile non fa la multa perché conosce chi ha infranto e chiude dieci occhi. Però poi a me viene rinfacciato un tono da insulto con tanto di ammonimento ufficiale senza che chi lo ha fatto sia riuscito ad addurre casi concreti. Mi augurerei un minimo di trasparenza e di democrazia! Amplio la domanda. Se qualcuno scrive "secondo me stai monopolizzando il sito" come l'ho fatto io con @charo e altri in diversi modi, questa non è una offesa, ma una critica.

Aspetto volentieri feedback da altri membri della comunità. Per ora voglio solo puntualizzare che la chat in cui abbiamo avuto la conversazione non è privata, ma pubblica, e che tutti la possono leggere (è possibile organizzare una chat privata, ma in questo caso non è stato fatto).

@DenisNardin Potresti darmi il link della chat di ieri, che non riesco a trovare?

Voilà

@DenisNardin Manca un pezzo: "ma guarda che qui stiamo parlando nonostante il medium" implica che tu in BETA abbia scritto qualcosa sul medium o sul discutere, cosa che non è rintracciabile. Un "ma" iniziale è sempre una obiezione a una affermazione precedente. Non inizierei mai una conversazione con un "ma" non motivato da un "turn" altrui precedente.

C'è un pulsante per ottenere i messaggi precedenti, in alto ("Load older messages").

@DenisNardin. Benissimo, grazie. Ecco la tua affermazione "Onestamente ho trovato la reazione di DaG esagerata, ma i tuoi messaggi talmente oltre l'accettabile che sono incline a perdonargli un po' di eccesso". Questo dimostra chiaramente due cose: la mancanza di coraggio e di democrazia!

Guarda, tira i giudizi che credi e gli altri che leggeranno tireranno i loro. Non credo abbia senso avere un'altra discussione qui.

@DenisNardin Questo è un posto per discutere e chiarire. Non ti ho esortato io a farlo, ma l'hai fatto di tua volontà. Non tiro nessun giudizio, ma espongo senza veli come sono avvenute le cose.

@DenisNardin Segnalo che sono spariti vari dei commenti che avevano destato mie e altrui reazioni negative. Gli amministratori sono in grado di reintegrarli?

@DaG Sii certo che non ho mai cancellato nulla. Al massimo ho fatto un edit.

Chi ha detto che hai cancellato qualcosa, @Nico? Io mi riferivo a situazioni come quella in cui un amministratore aveva cancellato qualcosa (https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11582/come-posso-tradurre-questo-uso-figurato-dello-spagnolo-farsa#comment27702_11582). Già che ci siamo, mi aiuti a ritrovare il commento che menzionava Queen Latifah?

@DaG Non ci sono commenti cancellati su questo post (eccetto uno mio dove avevo frainteso il problema), se intendi da altre parti manda una custom flag sul post in questione e daremo un'occhiata. Alcuni commenti però sono stati cancellati per una buona ragione e avrei un po' di ritegno a reintegrarli.

@DenisNardin Sì, mi riferivo ad altri post, come per esempio quello che menziono nel mio ultimo commento. Non mi ricordo che cosa vi si dicesse, ma visto che qua si parla di “casi concreti”, è possibile che alcuni non siano più accessibili.

@DaG Eccotelo: "Temo che qui lo spirito di combriccola latineggiante con tutte le sue implicazioni regni alla stragrande. Non esiste interesse vero, ma solo "se tu dai una cosa a me, io poi do una cosa a te". O forse meglio a mo' di Queen Latifah "When you are good to Mama, Mama is good to you".

@linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Aggiungo che quando tu hai scritto- a mio avviso giustamente- di esserti sentirti ferito, ti si è risposto che la prendevi personalmente senza motivi concreti, mentre quando l'ha fatto charo sono arrivati in massa quelli della Croce Rossa. Un peso e due misure.

Che cosa costituisca insulto è, fino a un certo punto, soggettivo. Escludiamo gli “insulti” che si scambiano due amici e vediamo qualche esempio.

Riferirsi a qualcuno come "il/la ⟨nazionalità⟩” in frasi assolute è un insulto, più che maleducazione.
Dare a qualcuno del “Neanche i gesuiti, non so se ci sei o ci fai” è un insulto nei confronti della persona a cui ci si rivolge e anche dei gesuiti.
“Codardo/a” è un insulto.

Bastano? Anche dare del troll è un insulto, se non accompagnato da un'analisi specifica dei motivi che ci spingono ad adoperare il termine. Mi spiego: dire a qualcuno in chat “sei un troll” è un insulto; “siccome A, B e C, mi viene il dubbio che tu sia un troll” non è un insulto.
Dal dizionario Treccani per insulto (primo significato)

Grave offesa ai sentimenti e alla dignità, all’onore di una persona (per estens., anche a istituzioni, a cose astratte), arrecata con parole ingiuriose, con atti di spregio volgare (come per es. lo sputo, un gesto sconcio, ecc.) o anche con un contegno intenzionalmente offensivo e umiliante.

L'ultima parte si applica agli esempi citati sopra.

@linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Perché? Volevo essere sicuro di interpretare correttamente il termine e vedo che un autorevole dizionario mi conforta.

Mah, perché la sensibilità è individuale, perché credo che tutti (qui) sappiamo di che cosa si stia parlando, perché in parte contraddice ciò che avevi scritto appena sopra, e che apprezzo molto più del Treccani. Non sono un affezionato delle citazioni (non so se hai letto certi miei post) e neanche dei dizionari perché ritengo che essi non siano una bibbia.

E' "scivoloso" anche dire che riferirsi a qualcuno usando la sua nazionalità sia un insulto più che una maleducazione. Secondo il contesto, è più probabile che sia maleducazione, e a volte non è per niente offensivo. Nel contesto specifico, secondo me, le parole di Nico erano un espediente polemico senza alcuna intenzione di insultare. Se applichi alla lettera le parole del Treccani, allora Nico non ha recato alcun insulto. Ma, ripeto, non voglio fare polemica.

@linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Se qualcosa sia un insulto o meno è in parte personale, ma ti assicuro che in questi giorni ho verificato con numerose parti terze proprio per essere sicuro che non fossero mie fisime, e il verdetto è stato unanime: Nico ha ripetutamente insultato vari partecipanti di questo sito. Questo non è considerato un comportamento accettabile qui. Ho provato a fargli capire che il fatto che lui consideri quelle espressioni insulti o no conta solo fino ad un certo punto, ma mi sembra chiaro che non voglia capire.

@DenisNardin io sto parlando solo della citazione del Treccani, e il riferimento alle parole di Nico era per spiegare che, secondo quella citazione, quelle non costituivano insulto. E non mi sto opponendo al tuo pensiero: io ritengo che Nico abbia alzato troppo i toni come, un po', anche altri; è stato un crescendo. La citazione dal dizionario, qui, mi fa venire in mente un cowboy abituato a sparare in aria per richiamare l'attenzione dei suoi collaboratori in mezzo alle praterie; se il cowboy va a fare la serenata alla sua fidanzata, non credo che dovrebbe sparare in aria per chiamarla!

@linuxfansaysReinstateMonica The only thing I'll say is that I have a wildly different perception of what happened. I saw Nico repeatedly provoking others until a few of them snapped with perhaps inappropriate reactions, and when asked to tone it down he doubled down in even more aggressive tones. When everyone else tells you you are being offensive, it's advisable to stop for a second and reflect on your behavior, not to scream that your freedom of expression is being restricted.

I agree with you @DenisNardin. But I don't understand why you are insisting on Nico, when I am talking about a citation from a dictionary. Well, trying. Ok, let's stop here, I think we both have exposed our thoughts.

Direi che l'uso di epiteti è un buon punto di partenza.
Riferirsi a Charo come "la spagnola" è sicuramente maleducato, e la maleducazione è, secondo le regole vigenti in tutte le comunità SE, una base per sanzionare.
Accusare qualcuno di essere un troll è senza dubbio un comportamento da sanzionare. Vi sono canali ben consolidati per segnalare comportamenti da troll.

Riporto qui la definizione del verbo "trollare" del Garzanti (grassetto mio):

(Internet) in un newsgroup, un forum, una chat ecc., comportarsi da troll, partecipare soltanto per disturbare, creare confusione e provocare litigi

Io questo l'ho sperimentato in prima persona su questo sito e, purtroppo, credo che adesso non l'abbia sperimentato soltanto io.
